# SU2 vs OpenFoam for highly unsteady aerodynamics. Suggestions?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, cfd, aircraft-design

I am trying to simulate aerodynamic interactions between high speed propeller downwash and wings of a cruising aircraft. Confused between OpenFoam and SU2. Open to other opensource software suggestions. Can someone please guide?

Also, pointwise vs Gmesh for complex propeller geometry, suggestions?

Comment: What are you confused about?